# google maps get new address info after marker was dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've created a autoComplete form so a user doesn't have to type in all address fields. In the bottom I included a map and street view for the location he chose from autoComplete, however after a user dragged the marker around I wanna update all the fields to show the updated marker position but I'm only able to get the updated **latitude/longitude** not the new **place name**, **city**, **zip code** etc. have a look at my code (the code I need help with is at the bottom) and thank you for helping.

```
//autocomplete address functionality
    function initMap() {
        var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            //auto fill the address fields
            document.getElementById('city2').value = place.name;
            document.getElementById('cityLat').value = place.geometry.location.lat();
            document.getElementById('cityLng').value = place.geometry.location.lng();
            document.getElementById('city').value = (place.address_components[3].long_name);
            document.getElementById('state').value = (place.address_components[5].long_name);
            document.getElementById('zip').value = (place.address_components[7].short_name);
            loadMaps();
        });
    }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);


function loadMaps() {
        //add map to page
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
            zoom: 17,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng($('#cityLat').val(), $('#cityLng').val()),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scrollwheel: false
        });
        //add marker to map
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng($('#cityLat').val(), $('#cityLng').val()),
            //title: 'Hello World!'
        });
        //add street view map
        var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng($('#cityLat').val(), $('#cityLng').val()),
            scrollwheel: false,
            pov: {
                heading: 34,
                pitch: 10
            }
        });
        //functionality to unfreeze the map
        $('#panelMaps').on('click', function () {
            map.setOptions({ scrollwheel: true });
            panorama.setOptions({ scrollwheel: true });
        });
        //update address field based on drag-able marker
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function () {
            document.getElementById("cityLat").value = marker.getPosition().lat();
            document.getElementById("cityLng").value = marker.getPosition().lng();
            loadMaps();
            document.getElementById("city2").value = 'add place name here'
            document.getElementById("city").value = 'city here'
            document.getElementById("state").value = 'state here'
            document.getElementById("zip").value = 'zip code here'
        });
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [google api reverse geocode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32415365/google-api-reverse-geocode)