# How to reverse geocoding and repopulate menu in real time dragging marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, drop-down-menu, google-maps-markers, reverse-geocoding

I have following javascript code:

```
function getLatLng() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById('address2').value;

     var input = document.getElementById('address2');
    var options = {
    types: [],
    };

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
            $('#lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
            $('#lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
function getLatLng2() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var e = document.getElementById('city');
var address = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
            $('#lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
            $('#lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
function getLatLng3() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var e = document.getElementById('region');
var address = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
            $('#lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
            $('#lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
function getLatLng4() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var e = document.getElementById('province');
var address = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
            $('#lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
            $('#lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
function getLatLng5() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var e = document.getElementById('country');
var address = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
            $('#lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
            $('#lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
function getLatLng6() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var e = document.getElementById('continent');
var address = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
            $('#lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
            $('#lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
//

var whos = null;
var placedata = [];
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var map;
function getplaces(gid, src) {
    if ( !! placedata[gid]) {
        map.setCenter({
            lat: parseFloat(placedata[gid].lat),
            lng: parseFloat(placedata[gid].lng)
        });
        switch (src) {
            case "continent":
                map.setZoom(3);
                break;
            case "country":
                map.setZoom(5);
                break;
            case "province":
                map.setZoom(6);
                break;
            case "region":
                map.setZoom(7);
                break;
            case "city":
                map.setZoom(8);
                break;
        }
        codeAddress(placedata[gid].name);
    }

    whos = src;


    //  var  request = "http://ws.geonames.org/childrenJSON?geonameId="+gid+"&callback=getLocation&style=long";
    var request = "http://www.geonames.org/childrenJSON?geonameId=" + gid + "&callback=listPlaces&style=long";
    aObj = new JSONscriptRequest(request);
    aObj.buildScriptTag();
    aObj.addScriptTag();
}

function listPlaces(jData) {
    counts = jData.geonames.length < jData.totalResultsCount ? jData.geonames.length : jData.totalResultsCount;
    who = document.getElementById(whos);
    who.options.length = 0;

    if (counts) who.options[who.options.length] = new Option('Select', '');
    else who.options[who.options.length] = new Option('No Data Available', 'NULL');

    for (var i = 0; i < counts; i++) {
        who.options[who.options.length] = new Option(jData.geonames[i].name, jData.geonames[i].geonameId);
        placedata[jData.geonames[i].geonameId] = jData.geonames[i];
    }

    delete jData;
    jData = null;
}
function zoomto(gid) {
   if ( !! placedata[gid]) {
        map.setCenter({
            lat: parseFloat(placedata[gid].lat),
            lng: parseFloat(placedata[gid].lng)
        });
       map.setZoom(14);
   }
}

function codeAddress(address) {   
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (!!results && !!results[0] && !!results[0].geometry && !!results[0].geometry.viewport) {
                map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
            } else if (!!results && !!results[0] && !!results[0].geometry && !!results.geometry.bounds) {
                map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);
            } else {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            }
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });          

        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}

function codeAddress2() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address2').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}


window.onload = function () {
    getplaces(6295630, 'continent');
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        zoom: 3,
        center: {
            lat: 0,
            lng: 0
        }
    });
};
```

complete demo is [here (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/bp87ffwd/)
Selecting Continent, state, region, etc I get latitude and longitude

If I insert a draggable marker:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location,
          draggable:true,
          title: 'Drag Me!'

      });
```

Moving the marker in the map I want change in real time continent, state, city, etc in the menu. Is it possible? How?

Comment: geonames.org , never heard of it, but it looks pretty interesting, maybe.  See if this helps: After dragging the marker it puts address components in input elements; look for my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030800/google-places-api-with-search-engine-and-draggable-marker-and-that-puts-coordina/44080553#44080553

Comment: ok i will try to adapt your code

Comment: possible duplicate of [google api reverse geocode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32415365/google-api-reverse-geocode)

Comment: I think it will be difficult to repopulate the dropdown menu as dropdown menu depends on different api. Fixed existing fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/bp87ffwd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search the drop down "options" for the returned result from the geocoder.  It is possible that as the data comes from different sources, it may not find the correct result, but this works for me (at least for Wichita, KS), although it requires a drag for each address component.  At this point, to change that you would need to refactor your code.

```
function setDropdown(menuId, string) {
  var menu = document.getElementById(menuId);
  var selectedIndex = menu.selectedIndex;
  for (var option = 0; option < menu.options.length; option++) {
    if (nodeValue(menu.options[option]).indexOf(string) != -1) {
      if (selectedIndex != option) {
        menu.options[option].setAttribute("selected", "selected");
        menu.onchange();
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}

function displayAddress(address) {
  for (var p = address.length - 1; p >= 0; p--) {
    for (var t = 0; t < address[p].types.length; t++) {
      if (address[p].types[t] == "country") {
        setDropdown('country', address[p].long_name);
      }
      if (address[p].types[t] == "administrative_area_level_1") {
        console.log("admin_area_level_1=" + address[p].long_name);
        setDropdown('province', address[p].long_name)
      }
      if (address[p].types[t] == "administrative_area_level_2") {
        console.log("admin_area_level_2=" + address[p].long_name);
        setDropdown('region', address[p].long_name)
      }
      if (address[p].types[t] == "locality") {
        console.log("locality=" + address[p].long_name);
        setDropdown('city', address[p].long_name);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/bp87ffwd/2/)